# How to scrape whatsapp web using nodejs/python?

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, web-scraping, whatsapp

Whatsapp web after connecting to phone, shows complete chats and contacts.
But inside console.log(html), html content is still as if I am not connected to phone.

Is there anything on nodeJs side that needs to be done for authentication?

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

request('https://web.whatsapp.com/', function (error, response, html) 
{
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(html);
   }
});
```

Comment: technically you will not able to crawl web whatsapp with request module it could not fetch javascript rendered content.you need headless browser for that and moreover whatsapp require some serious authentication ..

Answer (score 2):

You can easily achieve what you are trying to do using selenium in Python. Once you scan the QR with your phone on the browser which is opened by selenium, you can start catching buttons and other stuff using selenium and automate typing and clicking.

I have made a chat-bot that diagnoses lung diseases from X-ray in Whatsapp, you can refer my code here: https://github.com/skaravind/Whatsapp-Radiologist

Hope it helps!